# How do I make the expo image picker dark themed

Tags: react-native, image, react-hooks, expo, image-gallery

### This is my current image picker function

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
  
    })
    
    console.log(result)

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri)
    }
  }
```

I am trying to make the pop-up gallery dark-themed. How do I do that?

Comment: Follow this issue. it has some solutions. https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/560

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation has a Theme component that would be perfect for this! You can use their default theme, or customize it however you want! Check out details [here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/)

Adding a theme to your project is actually super easy. Assuming you're already using React-Navigation, then you don't even need to download an additional dependency.

Create a new .js file called whatever you want, typical name would be `theme.js`. Inside paste this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
  },
};
```

This theme component has a whole bunch of props to choose from so make sure to check it out.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
const MyTheme = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
    background: 'rgb(242, 242, 242)',
    card: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    text: 'rgb(28, 28, 30)',
    border: 'rgb(199, 199, 204)',
    notification: 'rgb(255, 69, 58)',
  },
};
```

Now for the dark mode portion, React-Navigation has built in themes, default and dark: `import { DefaultTheme, DarkTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';`

Inside your navigation container, now all you have to do is call the theme you'd like to use:

```
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  DefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

export default () => {
  const scheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={scheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      {/* content */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

This is a great rudimentary way to get start with light and dark themes. Once you get the hang of it, you can implement State as well to make your app toggle between default and dark mode!